# Configuring RRAS with two static IP

Tags: networking, rras

Sorry about my bad english, I'll try to make it simple.

I have a windows 2003 server with two nic (Local area connection 1 & 2) and two static IP, one for public ip (130.185.72.-) which provides access to the internet and one for Interanet (10.201.2.-)to which only clients inside the country have access to.

The server is configured for "VPN" and "NAT" using RRAS.

Everything works fine with external IP and client can connect to it and have access to the internet.

What i need is to client connect server through the internal IP and have access to the internet too.

Problem is when I add local area connection 1 to the NAT, the interanet IP loses access to outside of server and report "timed out" when I ping it. but external IP is still working fine.

- Only Local area connection 1 has a default gateway.

i dont know how to set gateway for my clients but first, they use a PPTP VPN to connect the server (wich has no default gateway to set) and i dont have access to their internet adaptor to set a default gateway for them.

Answer (score 0):

On your server, the default gateway should be configured only on the external interface (the one with the public IP address); the internal interface (the one with the private IP address) should have no gateway. In RRAS, you should configure the external interface as "public" and the internal interface as "private".

On your clients, you should configure the server's internal IP address as the the default gateway.